# Issue with cucumber .feature files in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse-plugin, cucumber, eclipse-oxygen

I have downloaded **Natural** plugin for cucumber test framework on Eclipse Oxygen.(This plugin is the only one that shows up for cucumber in the marketplace).
After successfully installing the plugin (and restarting eclipse),I try to open a **.feature** file in the cucumber editor and  the following error shows up :(this is the case with all the .feature files)

> required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'Scenario:'

Due to this the cucumber option menu doesnt show up when I right click.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste exactly like this:

```
Feature: user creates facebook account
  I want to use this template for my feature file


  Scenario: validate first name fields
      Given User is on login page
      When User enters first name
      Then User verifies first name is present
```